# Find the equation of the parabola in which the ends of the latus rectum

Tags: analytic-geometry, conic-sections

Find the equation of the parabola in which the ends of the latus rectum have the coordinates $(-1,5)$ and $(-1,-11)$ and the vertex is $(-5,-3)$.

I could think of assuming the equation of parabola as $(y-k)^2=4a(x-h)$ and plug in those three points to get three linear equations and solve for the unknowns. But, I wonder if there's any other approach?

Answer (score 1):

$h$ and $k$ are the coordinates of the vertex, hence $h=-5$ and $k=-3$. As focus is $F=(-1,-3)$ (midpoint of latus rectum) and vertex $V=(-5,-3)$, then $a=VF=4$.

Answer (score -2):

Vertex $(h,k) = (-5,-3)$.

We know, Length of Latus rectum $=4a$, and the end points are $(-1,5)$ and $(-1,-11)$.

Now using the distance formula, we have
$$4a=[ (-1+1)^2 + (-11-5 )^2 ] ^{1/2}$$

or,
$$4a =(0+256)^{1/2}$$

or $4a=16$. Therefore $a=4$.

So the required equation of parabola is 
$$(y-k)^2 = 4a(x-h)$$

or,
$$(y+3)^2= 4\cdot4(x+5)$$

or,
$$y^2+ 6y +9 = 16x + 80$$

or
$$y^2 + 6y - 16x - 71 = 0$$